# Why does MySQL workbench tell me that semicolon is missing?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a stored procedure on MySQL workbench version 6.3.
I get a warning that in line 3 of my procedure code a semicolon is missing, but it's there.

This is the response i get:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 3

What has happened?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MigrateDescription()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter int;
    DECLARE abhid varchar(20);
    DECLARE text_d varchar(50);
    DECLARE text_e varchar(50);
    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT `abhaengigkeit`.`AbhId`, `abhaengigkeit`.`Text_D`, `abhaengigkeit`.`Text_E` FROM `p16altdatentest`.`abhaengigkeit`;
    OPEN curs;

    REPEAT
        FETCH curs INTO abhid, text_d, text_e;

        INSERT INTO `paragraph16`.`description`
          (`languageId`,`textKey`,`text`,`isDeleted`,`changedBy`,`changeDate`)
          VALUES
          (1, CONCAT('Dependancy_', REPLACE(abhid, '_', '')), text_d, 0, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        INSERT INTO `paragraph16`.`description`
          (`languageId`,`textKey`,`text`,`isDeleted`,`changedBy`,`changeDate`)
          VALUES
          (2, CONCAT('Dependancy_', REPLACE(abhid, '_', '')), text_e, 0, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    END REPEAT
END
```

Comment: Try `DECLARE counter int(11);`

Comment: Does the MySQL server report any error when you run the code?

Comment: **_@OP_**: You better post the _exact error stack thrown_ in WB

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy: Done

Comment: _**@PatrickPirzer**_: here is my answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22552626/767881

Comment: because you don't have a semi-colon at the end... I think MYSQL is quite strict in the sense of looking for the semi-colon to close a SQL statement

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy: Thank You! That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL Workbench sends the code as-is to the server.

MySQL uses `;` as a statement delimiter. When it encounters `;` on line 3 it thinks the statement that started with `CREATE PROCEDURE` ends and it is followed by many other statements. The first 3 lines of the code you posted are definitely not a valid `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html), in order to use `;` inside the body of a [`BEGIN..END` compound statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html) one needs to temporary change the statements delimiter to a different character or sequence of characters.

The command to change the statements delimiter is `DELIMITER` followed by the new delimiter to use. It doesn't need to be terminated using the current delimiter; it's enough to have it alone on the line.

Enclose your code into two calls to `DELIMITER` (to set a new one and then to restore `;` as delimiter):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MigrateDescription()
BEGIN
    -- The content of your procedure here, using ; as statement delimiter
END
//             -- This is where the CREATE PROCEDURE statement ends
DELIMITER ;    -- Restore the default delimiter
```

This is the standard MySQL way to create routines, triggers and other statements that include [compound statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html). It is not needed if the routine or trigger body contains only one statement (no `;` inside).